# Fileserver() always returns index.html

Tags: go

My project structure is as follows:

```
/rootfolder
    index.html
    main.js
    main.go
```

I'm trying to serve the static javascript file through FileServer(), which always returns the index.html as a response instead of the main.js

In main.go:

```
serveFile := http.StripPrefix("/res/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")))
http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
http.Handle("/res", serveFile)
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
```

Inside index.html main.js is referenced as follows:

```
<script src="/res/main.js"></script>
```

From the network tab in my browser, it appears that FileServer() is always returning the index.html file as a response to `/res/main.js`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register the file handler with a trailing slash to indicate that you want to match the subtree. See the [documentation](https://godoc.org/net/http#ServeMux) for more info on the use of the trailing slash.

```
http.Handle("/res/", serveFile)
```

Also, use Handle instead of HandleFunc.

The index file was served because "/" matches all paths not matched by some other path. To return 404 in these cases, update the index handler to:

```
func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
      http.Error(w, "Not found", 404)
      return
    }
    ... whatever code you had here before.
}
```